# Credit card cloned and money taken (UK)

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, identity-theft

My mum recently learned she had been charged for a use of her card to pay £28 at a pub in Nottinghamshire. Since she has never been to Nottinghamshire, it must have been her card details were stolen. The pub isn't linked to a chain of pubs that exist outside Nottinghamshire or anything like that.

Is there any way to get this money back? She called the bank and they said it's too low an amount to count as fraud... which seems to imply anyone stealing below a certain amount is free to do so.

Comment: Does she still have the card in her possession?

Comment: It would help if we knew which bank and card network (Visa, Mastercard etc.) this was, as some of them have more favorable fraud policies.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Money Advice Service](https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/en/articles/identity-theft-and-scams-what-you-are-liable-for).

> You’ll be liable for any unauthorised withdrawals made before you tell your bank or building society, up to a maximum of £50.

If you go to [FCA website](https://www.fca.org.uk/consumers/unauthorised-payments-account) they mention the following

> You may have to pay up to the first £35 of an unauthorised transaction if your card has been lost or stolen or misappropriated unless this was not detectable by you, or the bank, its agents or staff were at fault.

But for my confirmation, I will read the bank's T&Cs regarding unlawful withdrawal.

So you can get your mother to pester the bank for the reasons or statute under which they are refusing to return her money.

Comment: This answer presumes the card has physically gone missing, at least temporarily. If that's not the case, and the assumption of a "cloned card" holds, then this exception do not hold, and the general rule still applies that the bank is on the hook.

Comment: @MSalters I made no assumptions. It would be better if you follow the links and read. The points you mention are duly covered in the links.

Comment: @MSalters To me, "_You may have to pay... if your card was lost or stolen..._" implies that if your card _wasn't_ lost or stolen, you _don't_ (or shouldn't) have to pay. Depending on exactly what "_misappropriated_" covers (e.g. someone cloning it when used legitimately), that _might_ have kicked-in, except (to me) the "_not detectable by you_" clause gets you out of that (i.e. so long as they didn't clone it under you nose and you did nothing about it).